# What's wrong with this Python implementation of an addition algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, addition

I've started to follow Stanford's CS161 on Coursera, "an online course on Algorithms and Data Structures."

I've looked up to find grade-school algorithms around integer arithmetic.

I have the addition algorithm in pseudo-code and was interest in implementing it in **Python 2.7** (accordingly with MIT standards).

I've analyzed my implementation and think it's almost correct but the Python interpreter provided some feedback possibly on uninitialized lists and variables.

**Note** that I'm not fully proficient in Python and there may be some obvious syntactic mistakes due to a lack of knowledge in basic data structures and code structuring.

I have a few questions on the code below:

```
def add(a,b):
    i = 0
    carry = 0
    x[i] = [None]*N
    y[i] = [None]*N
    while x[i] > 0 and y[i] > 0:
        x[i], y[i] = a%10, b%10
        a , b = a/pow(10,i+1), b/pow(10,i+1)
        N += i
    for i in range(N):
        x[i] = x[N-i]
        y[i] = y[N-i]
        r[i] = (x[i] + y[i] + carry)%10
        carry = (x[i] + y[i] + carry)/10
    r[N] = carry
    return r
```

Description of the algorithm:

The `add()` function takes two N-digit integers a and b as input and returns an integer with N or N+1 digits corresponding to the sum of `a` and `b`.

It first breaks up `a` and `b` into lists of size N holding and storing the N digits of `a` (respectively `b`) by extracting each digit from the least powered digit to the digit with the largest power of 10.

It then replaces all `x[i]` with `x[N-i]` (resp. `y[i]` with `y[N-i]`) and then computes `x[i]+y[i]` by taking care of the addition's carry at each iteration.

The carry dynamically increments by value.
when the for loop ends, we assign the latest digit r[N] of the sum as the value of the carry (>=0).

**Questions:**

1. Is it a good thing to initialize the lists `x[i]` and `y[i]` by assigning its elements' value as `[None]` N times ?
2. With `x[i]` and `y[i]` initialized as such, should the `while` loop works again as my conditions are on `x[i]` and `y[i]`?
3. How to return an entire list namely the list `r[N]` ? Should we type return `r[N]` or just return `r` ?

Other useful contributions and comments are welcome.

Comment: Your question will receive better attention at [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please do not use the `[list] * int` initialization unless you know what you are doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Also, why are you assigning, e.g., `x[i]` to a list and then immediately asking if `x[i]` is `> 0`. While this comparison will work, it doesn't make a whole lot of intuitive sense and it would be better to use something more readable and clearer.

Comment: If your program produced an error then it will be easier to help you debug if you provide that output, e.g. the stack trace.

Comment: as it stands you are getting uninitialized list and variable "feeback" likely because you are referencing both `r` and `N` without having ever defined them as far as I can see

Comment: [None] * N would return a N sized list, so index N is out of bounds, the last index is N-1.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Why does everyone keep wanting to move things to Code Review? This isn't even on topic on Code Review. The code doesn't work!

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The following are \*all\* Off-Topic on Code Review: Code that does not work as intended. Example Code. Hypothetical Code. Pseudo-Code. Stub Code. Code that the OP didn't write or does not own. Questions asking us to extend a code's functionality. Code review has a tightly-defined scope: "Code that works as intended, that the OP understands, that they want general feedback about". Anything and everything else, including specific questions E.G. "How to reduce memory-usage in this algorithm" are Off-Topic and/or better asked elsewhere.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Please read [a guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that is fine, depending on the context. You could potentially do the nicer: `x = [None for _ in xrange(N)]`, but the performance is very similar and this is unlikely to be important - readability is what matters.
2. I would do `x[i] is None` to see whether the value is none, if 0 was a legitimate value. Otherwise, I'd just do `x[i]` which checks if i is not None nor 0 or False.
3. `return r`

Look at the following code. I fixed add(), including out of bound indexes, and algorithm problems. and then implemented addSimplified() which does the same without the additional helper arrays.

```
def add(a, b):

    N = max(len(str(a)), len(str(b)))
    carry = 0

    x = [None] * N
    y = [None] * N
    r = [None] * (N + 1)

    for i in xrange(N):
        x[i], y[i] = a % 10, b % 10
        a, b = a / 10, b / 10

    for i in xrange(N):
        r[i] = (x[i] + y[i] + carry) % 10
        carry = (x[i] + y[i] + carry) / 10
    r[N] = carry

    return r


def addSimplified(a, b):

    N = max(len(str(a)), len(str(b))) + 1
    carry = 0

    r = [0] * N

    for i in xrange(N):
        step = (a / pow(10, i) % 10)  + (b / pow(10, i) % 10) + carry
        r[i] = step % 10
        carry = step / 10

    return r

print add(100, 20), addSimplified(100, 20)
print add(166, 66), addSimplified(166, 66)
print add(1920606,  9500666), addSimplified(1920606,  9500666)
```

Comment: thanks, advance512, your answer is definitely helpful. I like to dive into primitive objects, data structures to build on more complex objects and data structures.